# Extjs panel draggable delegate (drag handle) - not working

Tags: extjs4, draggable

I'm trying to create panel draggable by an element inside that panel.
Unfortunately delegate property is not working in my code and whole panel can be used as drag handle.

What am I doing wrong?
How to fix this code?

I'm using extjs 4.1.1.

Thanks.

http://jsbin.com/ahipob/1/watch

```
Ext.onReady(function() {

    var btn1 = Ext.create('Ext.button.Button', {
        text: 'btn1'
    });

    var btn2 = Ext.create('Ext.button.Button', {
        text: 'btn2'
    });


    var panel1 = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        items: [btn1, btn2],
        draggable: {
            delegate: '#'+Ext.escapeId(btn1.id)
        }
    });



    Ext.create('Ext.Viewport', {
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        items: [
            panel1
        ]
    });
});
```